# Multiple Sheet Copying Data Set

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following code which creates a variable # of additional sheets in my workbook based on how many rows have names in them on my "Master" sheet column B.  This macro also copies the various names in Column B on the Master and pastes it in cell A7 on the additional sheets.  The last step I am having problems with is to also copy the following cells from the Master sheet to the newly created sheets:

Master: C7, E7, F7, J7, R7, S7, U7, V7, W7, X7, Y7, AA7
Created Sheets: A62, D21, D29, D23, D25, D36, I21, I29, I23, I25, I36, D45

Any thoughts are greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CreateAddtlSheets()

    Dim ListSh As Worksheet, BaseSh As Worksheet
    Dim NewSh As Worksheet
    Dim ListOfNames As Range, LRow As Long, Cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ListSh = .Sheets("Master")
        Set BaseSh = .Sheets("Stmt")
    End With

    LRow = ListSh.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ListOfNames = ListSh.Range("B7:B" & LRow)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With

    For Each Cell In ListOfNames
        BaseSh.Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        Set NewSh = ActiveSheet
        With NewSh
        On Error GoTo 0
            .Range("A7") = Cell.Value
            .Calculate
            .Cells.Copy
            .Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End With
    Next Cell

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End With
    BaseSh.Activate '--Select Base.

    Sheets("Setup").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If I follow, within `with newSh`, do `.range("A62")=ListSh.range("C7")` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
.Cells.Copy
.Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

does nothing as it copys then pastes to the same space. The comment from findwindow is correct just set the cells values the way you did

```
.Range("A7") = Cell.Value
```

Or are we missing somthing?